# Changing of tmp directory not working in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I wanted to change the tmp directory used by spark, so I had something like that in my spark-submit.

```
 spark-submit <other parameters> --conf "spark.local.dir=<somedirectory>" <other parameters>
```

But I am noticing that it has not effect, as Spark still uses the default tmp directory. What am I doing wrong here?

By the way, I am using Spark's standalone cluster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/configuration.html

In Spark 1.0 and later `spark.local.‌​dir` overridden by `SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS` **(Standalone, Mesos)** or `LOCAL_DIRS` **(YARN)** environment variables set by the cluster manager."

Answer (score 0):

OK, it looks like this option is deprecated. One method that works is to change the value of `SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS` in `spark-env.sh`. For example, like this.

```
SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS="/data/tmp/spark"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem on standalone Spark.

Although I set `SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS=/opt/tmp` in my `~/.bashrc`, I kept getting the error. Then set `hadoop.tmp.dir` to the same path `/opt/tmp` in my `mapred-site.xml`.